# Modify line behind QStatusbar widgets

Tags: c++, qt, statusbar, qt6, qstatusbar

Is there a way to modify (remove) the line behind a permanent widget in a QStatusbar?
[image: 1]

I don't know if it's important, but that's how I added the labels to the status bar:

```
wStyleTest::wStyleTest(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::wStyleTest)
{
    // ...

    ui->statusbar->addPermanentWidget(ui->lblPermWidget1);
    ui->statusbar->addPermanentWidget(ui->lblPermWidget2);

    // ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Subclass `QProxyStyle` and reimplement the `drawPrimitive` method. In there, check for the `QStyle::PE_FrameStatusBar` element and return from it instead of calling the base method.

```
#include <QProxyStyle>
#include <QStyleOption>

class StyleFixes : public QProxyStyle
{
public:

    void drawPrimitive(PrimitiveElement element, const QStyleOption *option, QPainter *painter, const QWidget *widget) const
    {
        if (element == QStyle::PE_FrameStatusBar)
            return;

        QProxyStyle::drawPrimitive(element, option, painter, widget);
    }
};
```

Apply it to your app either in your main.cpp or constructor of MainWindow:

```
QApplication::setStyle(new StyleFixes);
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick answer, it works! :-) But the QStyle member should be `PE_FrameStatusBarItem`.

Comment: The other one worked for me. Either way, glad it worked out